# ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I expected to download opencv-python on Raspberry PI 4, but found this issue.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install opencv-python
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.9.0.80.tar.gz (92.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      patching file opencv/3rdparty/openexr/IlmImf/ImfSystemSpecific.cpp
      /tmp/pip-build-env-1kcfvkob/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /tmp/pip-build-env-1kcfvkob/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1kcfvkob/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
          cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1kcfvkob/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
          self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1kcfvkob/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
          raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
      
      Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is /tmp/pip-build-env-1kcfvkob/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

My Raspberry PI model is as follows:

```
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : d03114
Serial      : 10000000973ffc25
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
```

The version of Python I'm running: `python3.9.0`

I tried the following, but it failed：

①`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (69.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.42.0)
```

But the problem mentioned at the beginning still exists

②Install a specific version of opencv-python`pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.3.56`, a very interesting thing happened at this point.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python==4.5.3.56
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-python/opencv_python-4.5.3.56-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl (10.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-python==4.5.3.56) (1.26.4)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.5.3.56
```

Shows that the download is complete (but only 10M!), also when I want to `import cv2`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.9.0 (default, Feb 13 2024, 22:18:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libIlmImf-2_5.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try `sudo apt-get install libilmbase-dev libopenexr-dev`, but

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install libilmbase-dev libopenexr-dev 
Reading the package list... Done 
The dependency tree of the package is being analyzed 
Reading status information... Done 
libilmbase-dev is already at the latest version (2.2.1-2). 
libopenexr-dev is already at the latest version (2.2.1-4.1+deb10u2). 
There are 0 packages upgraded, 0 new packages installed, and 0 packages to uninstall. There are 563 packages that have not been upgraded.
```

And then I don't know how to continue，I hope you can help me out。

Comment: Use pre-complied. Firstly, update and upgade, Secondly, install libraries sudo apt install python-opencv. Thirdly, https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/#write-comment

Comment: Thank you for your help.To install opencv-python on a 32-bit Raspberry PI, there are two other websites.①https://fernandezvictor.medium.com/installing-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-3fe36da91e86#838a;  ②https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/1ac8dbe8572f3f533df6269dab35df65. In addition to using Raspberry PI, it is important to pay attention to whether Raspian 10 (Buster) or Raspian 11 (Bullseye), because there may be compatibility issues between numpy and its glibc version. Raspian 10 (Buster) suggests using python3.7 and Raspian 11 (Bullseye) suggests using python3.9.